# Dudas básicas respecto a R

Tags: r

Recién estoy empezando a programar en R en la universidad y tengo varias dudas respecto a dos ejercicios, pues no consigo encontrar la solución.

El primero de ellos: Calcule e imprima la suma de todos los números enteros del 1 al 15 excepto el 12.
Yo lo hice de la siguiente manera, pero no creo que sea la correcta para este caso:
`d=sum(1:15)-12 print(d)`

El segundo de los ejercicios es: Dado un numero entero N, imprima la letra “A” N veces en la pantalla.

Como podrán observar, el nivel que tengo es muy bajo. Considero que no progreso adecuadamente y la manera de impartir clases de la profesora tampoco ayuda mucho, pues lo único que hacemos es copiarle el código y a la hora de realizar tareas por mi cuenta me como mucho la cabeza porque no se llevarlas acabo. Si alguien pudiera recomendarme por dónde empezar a estudiar y programar en R por mi cuenta lo agradecería mucho, y qué proyectos me recomiendan para ir practicando y encontrándole una lógica.

Disculpen las molestias y muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola. [R para principiantes](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/rdebuts_es.pdf). Está disponible para descarga gratuita.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor realiza el [tour] y consulta [ask]. Cuando tengas preguntas específicas sobre programación no dudes en venir. Debes plantear siempre lo que hayas intentado, tratando de ofrecer un [mcve].

Comment: Por que dices que esto `d=sum(1:15)-12 print(d)`no te parece correcto? ciertamente es una forma de hacerlo, la otra podría ser `x <- 1:15;sum(x[x!=12])`. El otro tema lo manejas con repeticiones: `N <- 12;rep("A", N)`